# Socket fread() sometimes return an empty string

Tags: php, sockets

I'm using some API to get a remote server's info by sending a packet with `fwrite()` and then read the returned value by `fread()`. Most of the times it works properly, but every 5 to 10 times, it will return an empty string from `fread()`. This is the code I use:

```
public function getInfo()
{
    @fwrite($this->rSocket, $this->createPacket('i'));

    $inforead = fread($this->rSocket, 999);

    if(strlen($inforead) >= 28)
    {
        $inforead = substr($inforead, 11);

        $aDetails['password'] = (integer) ord(substr($inforead, 0, 1));

        $aDetails['players'] = (integer) $this->toInteger(substr($inforead, 1, 2));

        $aDetails['maxplayers'] = (integer) $this->toInteger(substr($inforead, 3, 2));

        $inforead = substr($inforead, 5);

        $iStrlen = ord(substr($inforead, 0, 4));
        if(!$iStrlen) return -1;
        $aDetails['hostname'] = (string) substr($inforead, 4, $iStrlen);
        $inforead = substr($inforead, 4+$iStrlen);

        $iStrlen = ord(substr($inforead, 0, 4));
        $aDetails['gamemode'] = (string) substr($inforead, 4, $iStrlen);
        $inforead = substr($inforead, 4+$iStrlen);

        $iStrlen = ord(substr($inforead, 0, 4));
        $aDetails['mapname'] = (string) substr($inforead, 4, $iStrlen);
    }
    return $aDetails;
}
```

I also debugged `fwrite()` and it seems it returns the number of bytes written and not false, meaning the error wasn't in `fwrite()`. Is the problem with my code or with the server failing to provide the info?

The constructor opens the socket, so it won't be visible here.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered a strange stream socket situation, my fread code always returned empty string.

I replaced fread by [stream_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) and problem solved